# incorrect values in array in node-red

Tags: node-red

I am new to Node-Red and I need to create a small system where three input values of the power phase need to be summed. For this, I am using the "join" node to create an array. But the problem now is that the values from the array do not match the individual values in the power phase nodes. Can someone show me how to create a simple array with three values (coming from different nodes). Or can someone help me sum three values from three different nodes? I WOULD greatly appreciate any advice.

PS: This is how it looks like at the moment

[image: This]

[image]

Comment: What is the `msg.topic` on each of the Power Phase nodes? They need to be different so the join node knows how to distinguish them